# Linking issue for Firebase Pod (in libFirebaseStatic.a)

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods, cpu-architecture

Was trying to add a pod (FirebasePerformance) to my Podfile

I can technically run the build on my local devices, but when I try to run on a Simulator I get the following error:

> In Pods/Firebase/libFirebaseStatic.a(FPendingPut.o), building for iOS
> Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file
> 'Pods/Firebase/libFirebaseStatic.a' for architecture arm64

Even when I removed the new pod (FirebasePerformance), it still is giving me the same error. I believe part of the reason for my issue was that I attempted to fix other issues by changing the cpu architecture that my cocoapods were installed in. But even after re-installing in both x86_64 (for simulators on Macbooks with M1 chips), and then deintegrating and trying to reinstall with arm64 (older Macbooks / iOS devices), it still is giving the same error. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be unsatisfactory for those who need to use the Firebase Pod (for whatever reason). But I found in this case, I could actually just delete the Firebase pod from my Podfile and re-install and the issue would be fixed. (It turns out all of the actual logic is presented in other pods like FirebaseCore, FirebaseFirestore, etc., and the "Firebase" pod is just a dummy one).